# Error Occur During JAR File creation For JAVA in Net Beans 7.3.1

Tags: java, jar

I am using Netbeans version 7.3.1. I am trying to create a JAR file for a Java application, but the following error was returned when I clicked the "Build" option on the context menu of the Java application in the Project window…

```
Created dir: D:\Java\Programe\JavaPrograme\build
Updating property file: D:\Java\Programe\JavaPrograme\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: D:\Java\Programe\JavaPrograme\build\classes
Created dir: D:\Java\Programe\JavaPrograme\build\empty
Created dir: D:\Java\Programe\JavaPrograme\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
D:\Java\Programe\JavaPrograme\nbproject\build-impl.xml:926: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Java\Programe\JavaPrograme\nbproject\build-impl.xml:268: Class not found: javac1.8
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Please share any solutions.

Comment: "give the solutions" - Yes Sir!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your your Ant version is below 1.9.

**Follow up these steps:-**

Go to preferences > Java > Ant. (For older versions, it is under preferences > Miscellaneous > Ant).

Look for something like "Apache Ant version 1.9 compiled on". If your Apache ant version is lower than 1.9, you will need to update your Netbeans or download the latest version of it.

Hope this helps.